# Characterising Flat Modules - Lazard's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

Please do **not** provide a full solution, I would just like a hint to set me on the right path. Working on an exercise in Lang's Algebra book, I am trying to prove that four conditions are equivalent, in order to prove Lazard's theorem: a module is flat if and only if it is a direct limit of finite free modules.  (Chapter 16 exercise 13).
There is one implication that has given me a lot of difficulty. There is a hint in the book that says this step should be easy from the hypothesis. It is as follows.

$P$ is finitely presented, $E$ is arbitrary, all modules are over a commutative ring $A$.
Suppose that $\text{Hom}(P,A)\otimes E\to\text{Hom}(P,E)$ is surjective. Let $f\in\text{Hom}(P,E)$. Then there exists a free module $F$ and homomorphisms $g:P\to F$, $h:F\to E$ such that $f=h\circ g$.

My initial thought was to let $F$ be the free module that maps surjectively onto $P$ in the finite presentation. We can write $f=\alpha\otimes e\in\text{Hom}(P,A)\otimes E$ by assumption. Then if $\pi:F\to P$ is the surjection in the finite presentation, we would have a candidate for $h$, namely $(\alpha\circ\pi)\otimes e\in\text{Hom}(F,E)$. The problem is that, for this to work, $P$ would have to embed into $F$. But then the sequence of the finite presentation would have to split, which I do not think is generally true. So this will not work. I've been stuck on this for a while, and the hint makes me think I am missing something obvious. A proper hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $f$? You didn't define it.

Comment: My mistake. It's just a homomorphism from $P$ to $E$. Corrected it.

Comment: B.t.w., why do you say that a submodule of a free module is free?  A trivial counterexample is a non-principal ideal of an integral domain which is not a P.I.D.

Comment: Ohh... of course. The ring has to be a PID for this to hold. Perhaps that will actually allow me to find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

By hypothesis, there are linear forms $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,A)$ and vectors $w_1,\dots w_n\in E$ such that
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(x) w_i\quad\forall x\in P.$$

Consider the map
\begin{align}
g:P&\longrightarrow A^n, \\
x&\longmapsto\bigl(v_1(x),\dots,v_n(x)\bigr).
\end{align}

Comment: I feel stupid for not considering this after multiple hours. Thanks. That gives the result immediately.

Comment: I don't think it's stupid. It happens to all of us to try a way which looks promising, but which is an impasse. Further, I had the chance to work with Prof. Lazard in the 80s…